# Ant Build failing because of wrong classpath to JBoss server

Tags: ant, jboss

How can I fix it or where do I fix it?

It should point to:

```
C:\jboss\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\lib
```

**Console log**

```
C:\PSC Updated\src>ant build-ejb
Buildfile: C:\PSC Updated\src\build.xml

clean:

build-core:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\PSC Updated\src\build\classes
    [javac] Compiling 159 source files to C:\PSC Updated\src\build\classes

BUILD FAILED
C:\PSC Updated\src\build.xml:110: C:\home\apps\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\lib does not exist.
```

Worked: When I pointed to my {jboss.home}\server\default\lib

Comment: post your build.xml it would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try double slash for windows path on ant files.

```
  C:\\jboss\\jboss-5.1.0.GA\\server\\default\\lib
```

Could you post your build.xml for more clarification.

Comment: I fixed it. The issue was with the location given in the build.xml.